# Can I change a user role from command-line in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface

I want to change a user from normal user to administrator in command-line. Is this possible? What command should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Net group is the command your seeking.

add user to local administrator group:

```
net group administrators /add adminguy
```

Comment: I presume you'll be prompted for the username/password of an actual admin before it succeeds?

Comment: No it wont prompt you for username/password. It checks the userlevel of the cmd window your typing it in. So in windows 7 you might have to right-click "command" and choose run-as administrator. Or put it in a bat script and run the bat script as administrator.

Comment: net group works with a domain group. You need to use net localgroup to add a user to a local group on a server. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc725622(v%3Dws.11)

Comment: Does this write to a specific file on disk? In linux, you can directly edit files in `/etc/sudoers` , `etc/groups`, ...